# Get link and Redirect with Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns

i have website with this domain `example.com` and have file like this `example.com/example.php` how to redirect all file to other website there have same domain name but different in extension
so it will redirect `example.com/example.php` to `example.net/example.php` with htaccess?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how to redirect all file? so i'm not need add all file
Thanks